If the lottery is truly random why do some numbers never appear as the first ball?
The Powerball Lottery consists of 5 numbers from 1 through 69 and 1 Powerball from 1 through 26.
Below is a table that shows the index range of each starting ball and how many combinations there are starting with that first ball.



FIRST BALL
START
STOP
TOTAL




01
1
21,174,010
21,174,010


02
21,174,011
41,102,490
19,928,480


03
41,102,491
59,841,210
18,738,720


04
59,841,211
77,444,250
17,603,040


05
77,444,251
93,964,026
16,519,776


06
93,964,027
109,451,316
15,487,290


07
109,451,317
123,955,286
14,503,970


08
123,955,287
137,523,516
13,568,230


09
137,523,517
150,202,026
12,678,510


10
150,202,027
162,035,302
11,833,276


11
162,035,303
173,066,322
11,031,020


12
173,066,323
183,336,582
10,270,260


13
183,336,583
192,886,122
9,549,540


14
192,886,123
201,753,552
8,867,430


15
201,753,553
209,976,078
8,222,526


16
209,976,079
217,589,528
7,613,450


17
217,589,529
224,628,378
7,038,850


18
224,628,379
231,125,778
6,497,400


19
231,125,779
237,113,578
5,987,800


20
237,113,579
242,622,354
5,508,776


21
242,622,355
247,681,434
5,059,080


22
247,681,435
252,318,924
4,637,490


23
252,318,925
256,561,734
4,242,810


24
256,561,735
260,435,604
3,873,870


25
260,435,605
263,965,130
3,529,526


26
263,965,131
267,173,790
3,208,660


27
267,173,791
270,083,970
2,910,180


28
270,083,971
272,716,990
2,633,020


29
272,716,991
275,093,130
2,376,140


30
275,093,131
277,231,656
2,138,526


31
277,231,657
279,150,846
1,919,190


32
279,150,847
280,868,016
1,717,170


33
280,868,017
282,399,546
1,531,530


34
282,399,547
283,760,906
1,361,360


35
283,760,907
284,966,682
1,205,776


36
284,966,683
286,030,602
1,063,920


37
286,030,603
286,965,562
934,960


38
286,965,563
287,783,652
818,090


39
287,783,653
288,496,182
712,530


40
288,496,183
289,113,708
617,526


41
289,113,709
289,646,058
532,350


42
289,646,059
290,102,358
456,300


43
290,102,359
290,491,058
388,700


44
290,491,059
290,819,958
328,900


45
290,819,959
291,096,234
276,276


46
291,096,235
291,326,464
230,230


47
291,326,465
291,516,654
190,190


48
291,516,655
291,672,264
155,610


49
291,672,265
291,798,234
125,970


50
291,798,235
291,899,010
100,776


51
291,899,011
291,978,570
79,560


52
291,978,571
292,040,450
61,880


53
292,040,451
292,087,770
47,320


54
292,087,771
292,123,260
35,490


55
292,123,261
292,149,286
26,026


56
292,149,287
292,167,876
18,590


57
292,167,877
292,180,746
12,870


58
292,180,747
292,189,326
8,580


59
292,189,327
292,194,786
5,460


60
292,194,787
292,198,062
3,276


61
292,198,063
292,199,882
1,820


62
292,199,883
292,200,792
910


63
292,200,793
292,201,182
390


64
292,201,183
292,201,312
130


65
292,201,313
292,201,338
26



Next, you can see the frequency with which every first ball appears throughout the years. It appears that beyond 40, it's pretty much pointless to pick any combination starting with 41 through 65.



01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10




78
73
72
56
63
57
50
48
46
45






11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20




40
40
25
40
26
34
27
28
36
20






21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30




17
19
23
17
12
08
16
13
07
11






31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40




05
06
04
02
07
04
07
03
05
05






41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50




02
00
01
01
00
00
01
01
01
01






51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60




01
01
00
00
00
00
00
00
00
00






61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
..




00
00
00
00
00
NA
NA
NA
NA
..



My question is why are there never any winning combinations that start beyond 40?

The TOTAL numbers in your first table are $\left({70-x \choose 5} - {69-x \choose 5}\right) \times 26$ based on all possible draws being equally likely (the numbers in your second table are very roughly this divided by $401375.5$ allowing for the noise of observing random variables).  This suggests any pattern is equally like to win, even if not equally likely to have to share the prize.

Note that Powerball has only had the 5/69 + 1/26 format since 2015. Before that it had fewer white balls (and more powerballs), which would skew your analysis if you included those results. That said, it seems you have results for ~700 draws, and a back-of-the-envelope calculation says there's been >1000 draws since 2015, so you're likely not including pre-2015 result, but it is something to be aware of.

The data provided is from October 7, 2015 and forward to accommodate for this.

Because they sort the numbers before reporting them, so in order for, say, 40 to show up as the first reported number, all five picks would need to be above 40.
A rough estimate of how often this happens is
$$(\frac{69-40}{69})^5$$
(I'm being very sloppy there), which is about 1%. As you are reporting just two digits that's enough to make it show up as 00.
Two things you could note:
1 - One can calculate an exact value, but I think this is enough to explain your observation.
2 - Note the general trend of the distribution decreasing. This is because reporting $n$ as the first value requires all picks to be above $n$, and this gets harder and harder to do as $n$ gets bigger.

I wonder why the OP didn't notice that the numbers are always ordered

@MartinBrandenburg - Yeah, I wondered that too. My guess is that we math folk are always sniffing around for patterns and regularities, but lots of people aren't. Either that, or I've guessed wrong (they didn't link to the actual data they used), and I'll have to delete this answer :-(.

Haha. Yeah. Well, I know they sort the numbers, but in the grand scheme of things, there are always 6 numbers being physically selected in a machine which makes it truly random. The general trend of distribution is indeed decreasing but this is mathematically so. How is it possible that the physical world would care? Meaning, air moving balls until they are selected while never really selecting anything above 40.

@suchislife - The first number reported is not the value on the first ball selected. Do we agree on that?

This is correct. Can't argue that.

The phenomenon you observed is not a property of the physical world, it is caused by people sorting the numbers before reporting them.

Meaning... 40 and above have technically come up many times UNTIL, the numbers were sorted and the sorting is what makes it harder and harder to do as n gets bigger.

Your statement "never really selecting anything above 40" isn't really valid - they get selected as frequently as any other number, but they are much more likely to have some other smaller number also get selected (and so they don't get reported first). It's kind of like how at the senior prom the basketball players are very unlikely to be the shorter partner when dancing with their date.

(I was typing up that long comment before I saw your last one.) Yes, I think your last comment says it well. Does it seem clear to you now?

"...much more likely to have some other smaller number also get selected." Yes. Indeed. I get it now. Love the prom example, haha. Thank you JZ!

@JonathanZ Not quite.  The first number reported is not the value on the first ball selected, unless the first ball selected happens to be the smallest of all the numbers selected.

See also order statistics. In particular, a sample's minimum is the distribution's first order statistic, and the link has formulas.

So the formula estimate for how often this happens is correct?

You mean the one in the body of my answer? No. I made some not 100% true assumptions to make the calculation easier, just to get an idea if we should expect 10% or 1%. The formula that Henry put in his comment looks like what I'd expect for the accurate answer (though I haven't verified it completely).

Hey, @suchislife, I rejected the edit you made, because my formula that you used is really just an approximation and not worth computing all the values. If you want to add it, maybe do it as a separate answer, or maybe better open a new question asking for a precise formula.

Sounds good. Thank you!
